# hash key value seems to be nil, but it shouldn't

Tags: ruby, for-loop, multidimensional-array, hash

So i searched for like an hour now, but i sadly couldn't find the solution. Right now i'am programming an Algorithm, that removes every hash from an array, that contains a date that is higher than the actual date.

Here is the code:

```
time = Time::now().strftime('%e.%-m.%y %k:%M')
@rows = [{"ID" => 1, "date" => 10.6}, {"ID" => 2, "date" => 25.5}]
max = @rows.length
p max
(0..max).each do |i|
    a = @rows[i]["date"].to_i 
    b = @rows[i]["date"]%1 
    a1 = time.to_i
    b1 = time%1

    if b == b1 then
        if a <= a1 then
            @rows.delete_at(i)
        end
    end         
end
p @rows
```

The problem is, that `@rows[ i ]["date"].to_i` seems to be nil. But it works when i do `@rows[ 0 ]["date"].to_i`.

Here are some things that i've already tried but didn't worked out:

```
a = @rows[i]["date"].to_i unless @rows[i]["date"].nil?

a = @rows.at(i)["date"].to_i unless @rows[i]["date"].nil?
```

also, here is the error i got every single time:

```
lab.rb:6:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass   (NoMethodError)
    from lab.rb:5:in `each'
    from lab.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

I'm so confused i hope someone can help me qq

Comment: Note: This should be `Time.now.strftime(...)`. Empty arguments are omitted. The `::` separator should be for namespace navigation only.

Comment: This is perhaps one of the quirkiest ways I've seen to compare dates. Are you using 10.6 to represent "June 6th"? If you use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format you can compare string to string: `%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@rows` is Array of Hashes.

So `@rows[0]` is first element of `@rows`, which is `{"ID" => 1, "date" => 10.6}`.

And `@rows[0]['date'] == 10.6`

**Update**
Oh, and what does 10.6 and 25.5 mean? Does it day and month of current year? If so - you code is wrong.
Also,  you solution is very bad. You try to mutate `@rows`, when iterate over it.

The solution can look like this:

```
current_time = Time.now
current_day, current_month = current_time.day, current_time.month

rows = [
  { 'ID' => 1, 'date' => 10.6 },
  { 'ID' => 2, 'date' => 25.5 }
]
rows = rows.select do |row|
  day, month = row['date'].to_s.split('.').map(&:to_i)
  month < current_month || (month == current_month) && (day <= current_day)
end

p @rows
```

But I prefer you to change format of date, that you use.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i wanted! ye 10 is the day and 6 the month. I am using this format because it's the easiest format i can get from my sql database using the sqlManager. I am doing this for a simple school project, using the stuff i learned in school. e.g i didnt know about mutating arrays, .map, split etc :D

Comment: "Easiest" is extremely debatable here. You're going to be in trouble come December when the next January is considered in the past. Use YYYY-MM-DD format whenever possible, *especially* here.

Comment: My programm will just work until july, so i'll be fine with my current format just now.